# Why do named parameters appear to work in PHP?

Tags: php, named-parameters

I recently discovered some code in PHP that appeared to use named parameters, and was surprised.

```
$this->setCellPaddings ($left = '', $top = '', $right = '', $bottom = '1');
```

Unfortunately a quick test confirmed my fear: only the order matters.  If I remove the first three parameters, and only pass in `$bottom`, I would expect everything to still work, but instead this is interpreted based purely on position, and so the left-side padding is set by this function, and not the bottom padding.

```
$this->setCellPaddings ($bottom = '1');
```

And a little Googling confirmed that [named parameters for PHP are still just an RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/named_params).

So: why does this work?  Why does PHP allow you to insert the assignments into the places where the values are expected?

Comment: It might be nice to clarify that in your second code example, the variable `$bottom` outside the function will have the value `1` while to the function, it looks like you are just passing the first argument so `$left` will have the value `1`.

Comment: Good point.  A casual reader might not notice that the position of the "named parameters" changed and thus broke everything.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?  It's useful information, that not everyone will know.  It's useful to have this on StackOverflow.  The answer is not obvious to everyone.

Answer (score 2):

This works because assignments are expressions that return values:

```
$a = $b = '1';
var_dump($a);
```

Outputs:

```
string(1) "1"
```

I.e., the code appears to be passing a value and setting a variable to it at the same time. Versus:

```
$left = '';
$top = '';
$right = '';
$bottom = '1';
$this->setCellPaddings($left, $top, $right, $bottom);
```

I'm guessing the author did this because the variables are used again later.

Comment: I suspected this was the case, but I figured this was useful info to have on StackOverflow, and I also guessed that someone could answer faster than I could conduct my tests to confirm my suspicion that this is how PHP handled assignments.  You win!

Comment: Some coding styles call for this kind of assignment even if you *don't* use the variables later, simply because it clarifies what your call is doing without the reader having to look at the function/method signature.

Comment: Yes, I may use it that way, although I'm a little concerned about the side effect of setting variables which have scope beyond the function invocation.

Comment: If you're concerned about readability of the invocation, you might consider converting the function definition to use an associative array instead, then you can do: `$foo->bar(['bottom' => 1, 'left' => 0])`

Answer (score -2):

They're NOT named parameters. They are regular parameters with *default* values (for when they're omitted from the call). If you omit parameters, it has to be from right to left.

Comment: Not me, but it's not perfectly correct.  What you said would be correct if the code I had posted had been a function signature, but it was a function call.

Comment: It's not correct. He's showing the function invocation, not the function definition.

Comment: @PhilPerry: was that you downvoting my question for revenge?